# Sequential numerical integration in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, numerical-integration

I am trying to write the program in MATLAB to perform sequential integration. First I define the first integral `n_array_exact{1}()` and save it as function handle in the array. This first integral becomes a function of `x` only after the integration. As a next step I use this function to calculate  next double integral (call it `n_array_exact{2}(x)`) w.r.t `mu1` and `s`. Before substituting `n_array_exact{1}(x)` to calculate `n_array_exact{2}(x)`, I replace `x` in `n_array_exact{1}(x)` to a function called `xp(x, mu1,s)` instead.

```
% Ordinary integration 
n_array_exact{1} = @(x) integral(@(mu) exp((x.*mu)), -1,1)/2;

xp2= @(x,mu1,s) sqrt(x*x +s*s +2*x*mu1*s);
for i=2:3
    n_array_exact{i} = @(x) integral2(@(mu1,s) exp(-s.*mu1.*x).*n_array_exact{1}(xp2(x,mu1,s)),  0,1,-1,1);

end
n_array_exact{2}(0.05)
%n_array_exact{3}(0.05)
%n_array_exact{4}(0.05)
```

After performing the integration and trying to evaluate `n_array_exact{2}0.05)` I got the following errors:

```
Error using  .* 
Matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in @(mu)exp((x.*mu))


Error in integralCalc/iterateScalarValued (line 315)
                fx = FUN(t);

Error in integralCalc/vadapt (line 133)
            [q,errbnd] = iterateScalarValued(u,tinterval,pathlen);

Error in integralCalc (line 76)
        [q,errbnd] = vadapt(@AtoBInvTransform,interval);

Error in integral (line 88)
Q = integralCalc(fun,a,b,opstruct);

Error in @(x)integral(@(mu)exp((x.*mu)),-1,1)/2


Error in @(mu1,s)exp(-s.*mu1.*x).*n_array_exact{1}(xp2(x,mu1,s))


Error in integral2Calc>integral2t/tensor (line 229)
        Z = FUN(X,Y);  NFE = NFE + 1;

Error in integral2Calc>integral2t (line 56)
[Qsub,esub] = tensor(thetaL,thetaR,phiB,phiT);

Error in integral2Calc (line 10)
    [q,errbnd] = integral2t(fun,xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax,optionstruct);

Error in integral2 (line 106)
    Q = integral2Calc(fun,xmin,xmax,yminfun,ymaxfun,opstruct);

Error in @(x)integral2(@(mu1,s)exp(-s.*mu1.*x).*n_array_exact{1}(xp2(x,mu1,s)),0,1,-1,1)


Error in test (line 10)
n_array_exact{2}(0.05)
```

Comment: `n_array_exact{1}` takes a scalar input only, you can't pass an array of `x` values into it. But `integral2` requires a function that accepts arrays as inputs. To resolve this, try `n_array_exact{1} = @(x) arrayfun(@(x) integral(@(mu) exp(x.*mu), -1,1)/2,x);`

Comment: Hello David, I have modified my code alittle bit, namely added varaible dependent integration limit to double integral (see my comment in the first post )  Got the following error Error using integral2 (line 76)
XMAX must be a floating point scalar.

Error in @(x)integral2(@(mu1,s)exp(-s.*mu1.*x).*n_array_exact{1}(xp2(x,mu1,s)),0,s_max,-1,1)


Error in test (line 11)
n_array_exact{2}(0.05)
  Any ideas?

Comment: `s_max` is a function handle, it should be a number I guess you need to evaluate the function.

Comment: But can I not have it as function or varible dependent limit ?Can I fix it somehow? I know that u can have variable dependent integration limit in simple 2d integral but here it is more complicated case ... it complains about n_array_exact and i dont see why?

Comment: Hi, I rolled back your edit, as it seems to have changed the question rather much. If you have a new question, please ask it as a separate question. The model Stack Overflow has is a single, well-contained question per post. That way problems are more easily searched for afterwards.